# Python app created with PyInstaller does not run on MacOS

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, pyinstaller, macos-big-sur

I have written a simple python program that I want to be able to run from my desktop as an .app file. I am running on macOS Big Sur and trying to use PyInstaller to bundle the app. Here is an image of the working directory before bundling:

[image: Project Working Directory]

"main.spec" is the spec file that PyInstaller uses. Here are the contents of the file:

```html
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('data.db', '.'), ('logo.png', '.')],
             hiddenimports=['pyperclip'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name='main.app',
             icon=None,
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

The program is windowed so I ran the following command from the working directory:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile main.py
```

Here is the output in terminal:

```html
josiahbrown ~/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager$ pyinstaller --windowed --onefile main.py                                    ✖ ✹ ✚ ✭main 
43 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
43 INFO: Python: 3.9.6
62 INFO: Platform: macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit
63 INFO: wrote /Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager/main.spec
67 INFO: UPX is not available.
68 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager',
 '/Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager']
72 INFO: checking Analysis
72 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
72 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
73 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
78 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1614 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'.
1615 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9'
3433 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
3521 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3526 INFO: Analyzing /Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager/main.py
3539 INFO: Processing module hooks...
3539 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3601 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3602 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3619 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3746 INFO: checking Tree
3747 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
3747 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
3753 INFO: checking Tree
3753 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
3753 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
3821 INFO: checking Tree
3821 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
3821 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
3822 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3881 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3884 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3885 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3886 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3887 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3888 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3894 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3924 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3934 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
3954 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
3956 INFO: Including run-time hook '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
3958 INFO: Including run-time hook '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
3963 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
4018 INFO: Looking for eggs
4018 INFO: Using Python library /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python
4020 INFO: Warnings written to /Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager/build/main/warn-main.txt
4036 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager/build/main/xref-main.html
4046 INFO: checking PYZ
4046 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
4047 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager/build/main/PYZ-00.pyz
4319 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager/build/main/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
4323 INFO: checking PKG
4323 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
4324 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
7158 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
7164 INFO: Bootloader /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Darwin-64bit/runw
7164 INFO: checking EXE
7164 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
7164 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
7164 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager/dist/main
7169 INFO: Fixing EXE for code signing /Users/josiahbrown/PycharmProjects/day-29-password-manager/dist/main
7171 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
7177 INFO: checking BUNDLE
7177 INFO: Building BUNDLE because BUNDLE-00.toc is non existent
7177 INFO: Building BUNDLE BUNDLE-00.toc
7181 INFO: moving BUNDLE data files to Resource directory
```

Here is an image of the resulting directory:

[image: Working Directory After Running PyInstaller]

Yet when I try to run "dist/main.app", nothing happens. I am expecting a tkinter window to appear. Is my spec file incorrect? When I try to run without the --onefile option, it does not seem to work either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try running `./dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/main` (or something thereabouts; either way, the path to the bundled executable) in the console... it's possible an exception happens you can't know about since there's no output. Alternatively, as a low-tech solution, wrap the main entry point in a `try: except Exception as e:` block and write the exception, if any, to a known place such as `/Users/josiahbrown/error.txt`...

Comment: Ok. I ran the bundled executable and this is the output:
josiahbrown ~$ /Users/josiahbrown/.../dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/main ; exit;              
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
[36450] Failed to execute script main
Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: It looks like the import for 'pyperclip' is not working. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: There you go then -- the `pyperclip` module is missing from your app bundle. Look at the Pyinstaller output when you create the bundle; it's probably telling you which modules it's adding to the bundle.

Comment: See: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules

Comment: @AKX I looked over the above link, but am not sure that I understand. The docs read: **The easiest thing to do in this case is to use the --paths option to list all the other places that the script might be searching for imports.** How do I know which paths to specify?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary - can you paste the output of the Pyinstaller command into your question to begin with? Also, can you try simply adding `"pyperclip"` into that `hidden_imports` list in the spec file?

Comment: I added `pyperclip` to the `hidden_imports` and ran again. I updated the question with the terminal output. The result seems the same to me.

Comment: The docs say *On Mac, this module makes use of the `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` commands*. Have you ensured that your executable can find them?

Comment: @BoarGules I have not checked that. How would I even check if the executable can find them?

Comment: Name them in the `.spec` file, maybe?

Comment: @BoarGules Where are you seeing this in the docs?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

Comment: @BoarGules I don't think it is specifically related to `pyperclip`. I just removed all references to the `pyperclip` module in my code and now I get a different error. Now it crashes because it can't find `logo.png` which is in the same folder as `main.py`. Not really sure what's going on...